Excel get data from cellA and based on that, print text in cellB but with the function in cellC so I can hide it
I am using the following equation:
=IF(G3="XXXX","A BB CCCC DD","")
But I want the 'TRUE' text to print to H4 and I want to place the function in cell BI3.
I have tried everything I can think of: concat, text, isnumber, &H4, xlookup, vlookup, etc.
Thanks
EDIT:
I don't want to have the function in the same cell the TRUE text is printed in because it is a form and H4 will have user's text if h3 does not contain the correct text. I don't want the function showing in the function bar because the user has to delete it to place more text.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That means you will have 2 functions. Why do you need it that way?

But on basis what logic the cell H4 to print the TRUE value returned using the one entered in cell BI3. Have you tried by simply referencing the cell BI3 to H4 which would show the TRUE value else it will show empty. Also it doesn't makes me to understand to use two cell references to print, when you can directly enter the formula in cell H4

I want the IF statement or whatever function to be placed in cell BI3 and print the TRUE text in H4 without having anything in H4.

Then this would need VBA - if excel functions/formulas are not an option. Or even you have a formula will it be ok to have the cell to be protected then one won't be able to see the function in the cell

I figured. I have tried several ways in VBA but will just have to do more research.
